# How to avoid javascript countdown timer not to go negative?

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I've got here a countdown, for testing purposes I have it set for **10 seconds**, but once It's perfected I'll have it as 30 minutes. Everything runs smoothly until the countdown goes negative, I want it to be negative, but in a proper format and for it to not jump from 0 to -01:00. `Math.Floor` seemed like a good idea, but with this code it ran with negative numbers right away. Also, once it is negative the format is -00:0-0, **I would like -00:00**.

How can the format be fixed once it's negative?

Please, refrain from object orientated, our web server is several years out of date.

```js
var seconds = 10;
function secondPassed() {
  var minutes = Math.round((seconds - 30)/60);
  var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60; 

  if (remainingSeconds < 10) 
  {
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
  }

  document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds > 8) {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; }
    else if (seconds == 8) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";}
    else if (seconds == 3) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
  }
  else{
    seconds--;
  }
}
var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
```

```html
<body onload = "getSeconds()">
  <p align ="center">
    <span id="countdown" style="color:black; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold"> </span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code for us to help you - your question is very ambiguous.

Comment: What do you mean by "object orientated"? This is client-side JavaScript, it runs on the visitor's computer. It has nothing to do with your server.

Comment: My mistake, some results I try to find don't work for me.

Comment: Note that the code you posted leaves times in the format X:XX, not XX:XX, if the time is less than 10 minutes. My answer, and the answer by @dave, take this into account.

Comment: @th30d0rab1e I am unable to do the edit myself -- please edit the code/snippet such that the font size is maybe, 20px. At 500px I am unable to view the results without resizing the window

Comment: @HunterStevens 20px as requested.

Comment: @th30d0rab1e the snippet is missing now... Can you put it back, so we can see the results in action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a floor function that rounds -0.5 to 0, and -1.5 to -1, as you require:

```
function floor(x) {
    return x | 0;
}
```

Here is a padding function that correctly pads an integer with 0s:

```
function pad(n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      n = -n;
    }
    if (n < 10) {
        return '0' + n.toString();
    }
    return n.toString();
}
```

Your code becomes:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var seconds = 10;

    function floor(x) {
        return x | 0;
    }

    function pad(n) {
        if (n < 0) {
          n = -n;
        }
        if (n < 10) {
            return '0' + n.toString();
        }
        return n.toString();
    }

    function secondPassed() {
        var minutes = pad(floor(seconds/60));
        if (seconds < 0) {
            minutes = '-' + minutes;
        }
        var remainingSeconds = pad(seconds % 60); 

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds--;
            if (seconds > 8) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; }
            else if (seconds == 8) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";}
            else if (seconds == 3) {document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";}
        }
        else{
        seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('secondPassed()', 1000);
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload = "getSeconds()">
    <p align ="center">
    <span id="countdown" style="color:black; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold">     </span>
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I get --00:00 once a minutes goes by, would you know why that happens?

Comment: Are you sure you have copied all of the code? The same thing does not happen for me.

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Please run it and let me know at what time the issue occurs

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way is to always treat seconds as positive, but then display a `-` if it is, in fact, negative:

```
var abs_seconds = Math.abs(seconds);
var is_negative = seconds < 0;
var minutes = Math.round((abs_seconds - 30)/60);
var remainingSeconds = abs_seconds % 60; 
if (remainingSeconds < 10) 
{
    remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
}
document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = (is_negative ? '-' : '') + minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
seconds--;
if (!is_negative) {
    if (seconds > 8) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green"; 
    } else if (seconds == 8) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    } else if (seconds == 3) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sdd8ubxh/2/

Answer (score 0):

For the rounding, I think using `parseInt()` rather than `Math.floor()` will get you what you're looking for (truncation).

As for the format, I think you will need to check whether remaining seconds is less than 0:

```
var isNegative = false;
if(seconds < 0)
{
    isNegative = true;
    remainingSeconds = Math.abs(remainingSeconds);
}
```

And then later prepend "-" if `isNegative`.